# how to use exiftool with cygwin basic startup

Tags: cygwin, exiftool

ok here is the situation.  I'm a complete newbie at all this and have no idea what is going on.  Currently I have a race website with thousands of photos and each time I basically upload via FTP to a temporary folder and use Cygwin with exiftool (I think) to tag each image and then use Cygwin to move them to where I want on my website.  During the process I make a filename.sh file and then do a chmod 755 and then tell it to run and I can tag several thousand photos individually with my filename.sh file data.  All that is good.  Most of the time.  haaha.

My question is I want to keep the images on my desktop and tag them using the same steps and then FTP them to my site.  So I think what I'm trying to figure out is how to get exiftool to work on my desktop computer the way it works on my website.

I tried to do all the right things, but when I run the filename.sh file it says:
**exiftool command not found**

What do I need to do?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: As It is not cygwin commad. What is the full path to exiftool ? How is called in you script ? Check also the full path to the desktop

Comment: hey thanks for the reply.  like i said i'm a total beginner, but have had help in the past getting things working from friends.  right now i'm uploading images to a server online and then i build a document to make a SH file (whatever that is) then i log into my server using cygwin.  i make the SH file active with a chmod and then run the SH file.  inside that file an example would be:

Comment: exiftool -v -overwrite_original -keywords="5600,5625,5627,5630,Amenya,Diriba,Boen,Rutto," ./event/1200px/01-vince/10031-UVM_0035.jpg       What I'm trying to do now is the same procedure but on my computer instead of online.   I've made the changes to my SH file to work with the photos on my computer, but when I run the SH file it says 'exiftool command not found' and it does that for each image in the SH file.  Any help?

Comment: update: solved.  i'm a newbie...and if anyone cares i finally got everything to work.  downloaded the exiftool for windows and followed those directions and moved the exiftool file to the right directory.  changed my .sh file to .bat file and ran my .bat file from the windows command line instead of cygwin..  bam.

Comment: Your answers are not very clear, so it is hard to help you. Again where is the exiftool program ? Is the path of exiftool reported in PATH ?

Answer (score 2):

install perl
then cpan Image::ExifTool
done.

Comment: Works and does not rely on outdated SourceForge projects.

Comment: I had to install wget, because for some reason it couldn't use curl on my machine..

Answer (score 1):

The `exiftool` command is available through Cygwin Ports, an extra package repository for Cygwin.

To install:

- Follow the Cygwin Ports installation guide (summarized here)

  - Download the regular Cygwin installer from https://www.cygwin.com/
  - In a cygwin terminal, run `cygstart -- /path/to/setup-x86.exe -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg`. The Cygwin installer should open.
  - On the Choose Installation Type page, select "Install from Internet".
  - On the Choose Download Site(s) page, select a regular cygwin distro mirror,  then enter ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports in the User URL field and press Add. Select both, then click Next.
- At the Select Packages screen

  - Set the View dropdown to "Full"
  - Search for `perl-Image-exiftool`
  - Click it to install it
  - Continue to click Next until the installation completes

https://sourceware.org/cygwinports/
https://sourceforge.net/projects/cygwin-ports/

Comment: 0
down vote
 

It is showing Unable to get setup from `<ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports/>`

Comment: Try using the url `<http://cygwinports.com/pub/cygwin/>` it seems more reliable, though I still don't see the package `perl-Image-exiftool` doesn't seem to be in that repository anymore.